# LENGTH() function in MySQL returning wrong rows

Tags: mysql

So I am trying to do this one,

> "Write a query to get the details of the employees where the length of
> the first name greater than or equal to 8"

and the expected outcome is this,

[image: expected]

So what I did is

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE LENGTH(fname) >= 8;
```

however whenever I try  to execute the code, the returned rows are not first names whose length is greater than or equal to 8

[image: returned]

EDIT: Additional picture
[image: output]

EDIT 2: it seems that from the file that I have imported, the columns for first name has whitespaces

Comment: What is the data type of fname column?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen VARCHAR(20)

Comment: What is the character set of the column / table? LENGTH() measures size in bytes. CHAR_LENGTH() measures size in characters.

Comment: @MattRaines where do I find the character set? also, I've tried the CHAR_LENGTH() and the returned rows are the same.

Comment: And you are sure that is the output of the query? Because your query returns the correct rows when I run it (assuming a single byte character set).

Comment: @MattRaines yes, I've added the action output. I hope it would help

Comment: What is the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE employees`? That will give the character set.

Comment: How did you import the values into the table? Might they contain trailing spaces or non-printable characters? To test, maybe try `CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(fname)) >= 8`.

Comment: @MattRaines it says DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4

Comment: Is it possible to include the actual queries you executed both to create the table and select the contents? As screenshots it's difficult to reproduce the problem, especially when some of the query is truncated with "...".

Comment: @MattRaines the CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(fname)) >= 8, worked, thank you

Comment: Is the field name `first_name` or `fname`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your values contain leading or trailing whitespace. Use TRIM() in addition to LENGTH(), eg `LENGTH(TRIM(fname)) >= 8`.

In addition the LENGTH() function measures the size of the string in *bytes*, whereas you are concerned with the size of the string in *characters*. All of which means depending on your character set you will get different answers for your query.

```
CREATE TABLE employees(employee_id INT, fname VARCHAR(20)) CHARSET utf8mb4;
INSERT INTO employees VALUES
    (100, 'Steven'), (101, 'Neena'), (102, 'Lex'), (103, 'Alexander');
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(fname)) >= 8;
-- +-------------+-----------+
-- | employee_id | fname     |
-- +-------------+-----------+
-- |         103 | Alexander |
-- +-------------+-----------+
-- 1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ALTER TABLE employees CONVERT TO CHARSET utf16;
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(fname)) >= 8;
-- +-------------+-----------+
-- | employee_id | fname     |
-- +-------------+-----------+
-- |         100 | Steven    |
-- |         101 | Neena     |
-- |         103 | Alexander |
-- +-------------+-----------+
-- 3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

ALTER TABLE employees CONVERT TO CHARSET utf32;
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(fname)) >= 8;
-- +-------------+-----------+
-- | employee_id | fname     |
-- +-------------+-----------+
-- |         100 | Steven    |
-- |         101 | Neena     |
-- |         102 | Lex       |
-- |         103 | Alexander |
-- +-------------+-----------+
-- 4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The alternative CHAR_LENGTH() function measures size in characters.

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(fname)) >= 8;
-- +-------------+-----------+
-- | employee_id | fname     |
-- +-------------+-----------+
-- |         103 | Alexander |
-- +-------------+-----------+
-- 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```